# Has it been ruled out that the Riemann hypothesis fails for only finite number of zeros?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Has it been ruled out that the Riemann hypothesis fails, but fails only for finite number of zeros?

Comment: No. (Comments must be at least 15 characters.)

Comment: A related post (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50186/if-the-riemann-hypothesis-fails-must-it-fail-infinitely-often)

Comment: @stopple, one trick is to append a dollar sign, a bunch of left and right brackets, and a dollar sign.

Comment: See?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Cool!${{{{{}}}}}$